# Convert character colony-forming units to numeric scientific notation in R

Tags: r, character, numeric

Say I have a following character vector with data on colony-forming units for a particular bacteria species

```
head(data$bacteria)
[1] "3*10^5" "2*10^6" "10^4"   "7*10^7" "3*10^6" "2*10^7"
```

I want the chr vector with theese arythmetics to be a vector with numeric result of this arythmetic expression in scientic notation so that I can run some statistical tests
I tried using `as.numeric` but it coerced the data to NAs

```
as.numeric(data$bacteria)
NAs introduced by coercion [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA...
```

How do I convert a character vector with math expression to a numeric result of theese expressions in scientific notation without loosing information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
sapply(data$bacteria, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Eg -

```
x1 <- c("3*10^5" ,"2*10^6", "10^4",   "7*10^7","3*10^6", "2*10^7")
sapply(x1, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] 3e+05 2e+06 1e+04 7e+07 3e+06 2e+07
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use he package **stringr** to substitute iteratively the components which make the conversion to numeric to fail.

Please have a look at the code below.

```r
library(stringr)

a <- c("3*10^5", "2*10^6", "10^4", "7*10^7", "3*10^6", "2*10^7")
# this replaces the string "*10^"
b <- str_replace( a, "\\*10\\^", "e")
# now we still miss those occurrences which do not start with a digit and "*"
c <- str_replace( b, "10\\^", "1e")

d <- as.numeric(c)
d
#> [1] 3e+05 2e+06 1e+04 7e+07 3e+06 2e+07
class(d)
#> [1] "numeric"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>